# Search for a string in all searched files gives /bin/grep: Argument list too long error

Tags: grep, find, xargs, error-handling

I tried the below command to search for in all files user `/var`

```
sudo find . -type f | xargs sudo grep 202007602 | tee /tmp/202007602.log
```

Output:

```
grep: ./www/html/jenkins/workspace/node_modules/xpath/docs/xpath: No such file or directory
grep: methods.md: No such file or directory
grep: ./www/html/jenkins/workspace/Efendibey-Live/node_modules/xpath/docs/function: No such file or directory
grep: resolvers.md: No such file or directory
sudo: unable to execute /bin/grep: Argument list too long
sudo: unable to execute /bin/grep: Argument list too long
```

Then, I tried a solution from stackoverflow but that too does not work and i get the below error:

```
sudo find /var -type f -exec sudo grep -l '202007602' {} + | tee /tmp/202007602.log
sudo: unable to execute /bin/grep: Argument list too long
sudo: unable to execute /bin/grep: Argument list too long
....
....
```

I'm using centos 7.

Can you please suggest ?

Comment: Why do you use `sudo` both on the `find` and on the `grep`? It should be enough to have `find` run with `sudo`.  Drop the `sudo` from `-exec sudo grep`.  Does that solve it?

Comment: In your first attempt, filenames are obviously being split. You need to use -print0 in find, and -0 in xargs, to fix this. In your second attempt, -exec requires a ";" to terminate the enclosed command.

Answer (score 0):

Let GNU `grep` do the work for you with its `-r` flag

```
sudo grep -r 202007602 /var | tee /tmp/202007602.log
```